# Can I apply a style to all website with stylish?

Tags: firefox-extensions

I am using the add-on stylish in Firefox 8.0. I particularly like a plain style and I want to apply to all website. Can I do that? I tried *.com and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a style to **all** websites by using the XHTML namespace:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

Your CSS here.
```

Alternatively, to only modify the Firefox UI, you would use the XUL namespace:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
```

So, if you *do not* include a namespace, Stylish will modify all elements in Firefox.

### Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you give an working example? Thanks.

Comment: I tried the first one you wrote and it didn't work.

Comment: @gunbuster363 See my edit. :)

Comment: It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

I found the XHTML namespace rule `@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);` to apply to everything, web sites and the Firefox UI (chrome) alike.

To style all web sites, I use the following `@document` rule instead (tested with FF28.0 and Stylish 1.4.3):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://), url-prefix(https://) {
    /* Make all Links UPPERCASE */
    a {
        text-transform: uppercase !important;
    }
}
```

Documentation on Mozilla Developer Network:

- [@namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace)
- [@document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document)